# Why do I get "Warning: Division by zero in __TwigTemplate"?

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

I created the connectedFilters.js file in /themes/custom/module/js/ with the following code.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

    Drupal.behaviors.connectedFiltersBehavior = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {

            console.log("im working!");

        }
    };

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

In module.libraries.yml I added the following lines.

```
connectedFilters:
  js:
    js/connectedFilters.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/jquery
```

In the appropriate view, above the top HTML element I added `{{ attach_library(‘module/connectedFilters’) }}`.

When I refresh the page I get the following warning.

```
Warning: Division by zero in __TwigTemplate_803bc8c08db6c9bfff48088195ee1e9f3bfaa4c94fad1e00b868ab6b41a67f00->doDisplay()
```

When I remove`{{ attach_library(‘module/connectedFilters’) }}`, the error goes away. Why?

Comment: `‘module/connectedFilters’` is not using the correct string delimiters. It should be `'module/connectedFilters'`. (In the question, the difference is more evident.)

Comment: Yep that was it, thank you.

Comment: ```{{ attach_library(‘module/connectedFilters’) }}``` is evaluating to 0/0 due to inappropriate inverted commas as mentioned by @kiamlaluno.

Comment: I'm fine if you close this, but it might be worth saving since the error message is so mysterious and doesn't relate to what caused the problem